# How do I search documents with their synonyms in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with some documents. These documents have the field `name`. But now, my documents are able to have several names. And the number of names a document can have is uncertain. A document can have only one name, or there can be 10 names of one document.

**The question is, how to organize my index, document and query and then search for 1 document by different names?**

For example, there's a document with names: "automobile", "automobil", "自動車". And whenever I query one of these names, I should get this document. Can I create kind of an array of these names and build a query to search for each one? Or there's more appropriate way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

## Tldr;

I feels like you are looking for something like [synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html)?

## Solution

In the following example I am creating an index, with a specific [text analyser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html).

This analyser, handle `automobile`, `automobil` and `自動車` as the same token.

```json
PUT /74472994
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": ["synonym" ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [ "automobile, automobil, 自動車" ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name":{
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "synonym"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /74472994/_doc
{
  "name": "automobile"
}
```

which allow me to perform the following request:

```json
GET /74472994/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "automobil"
    }
  }
}

GET /74472994/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "自動車"
    }
  }
}
```

And always get:

```json
{
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1.7198386,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "74472994",
        "_id": "ROfyhoQBcn6Q8d0DlI_z",
        "_score": 1.7198386,
        "_source": {
          "name": "automobile"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```